# How to query PostgreSQL to find the balance of a certain account?

Tags: corda

I was looking at `fungible_token` table inside my PostgreSQL database, and I noticed that all of my records have the same value for the `holder` field, and that value is the X500 name of my Wallet node; even though all my tokens are issued to accounts on that node (i.e. Wallet node is the host for all of my accounts).

Please note that I'm able to query account balances correctly inside my flows (I understand that it relies on querying the `vault_states` table and not `fungible_token`).

1. Is it by design that the `fungible_token` table is showing the `host` of the accounts as the `holder` of the token?
2. If so, what would be the proper SQL query to find the balance of a certain account?

Just to be more clear, I'm looking for a SQL that I can write inside pgAdmin - not inside Corda flows.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented my requirement in 2 ways:

- [Off-ledger](https://blog.b9lab.com/complementing-tokens-sdk-with-custom-reporting-e50df796a52d)
- [On-ledger](https://blog.b9lab.com/elevating-tokens-sdk-with-on-ledger-custom-reporting-57174ba614ba)

Also, Sneha Damle from R3 provided the SQL query to find an account's balance in [her article](https://medium.com/corda/cordas-accounts-tokens-making-blockchain-more-inclusive-for-everyone-3bf0c3993d41) (Database View paragraph).

Answer (score 0):

From our recent account library samples, you choose to issue the tokens to the Account directly. https://github.com/corda/samples-kotlin/blob/master/Accounts/worldcupticketbooking/workflows/src/main/kotlin/com/t20worldcup/flows/IssueCashFlow.kt#L42

That said, when you do a query, you just need to specifies the externalID to the AccountID.

For example:

```
class QuerybyAccount(private val whoAmI:String) : FlowLogic<String>() {
override val progressTracker = ProgressTracker()

@Suspendable
override fun call():String {
    val myAccount = accountService.accountInfo(whoAmI).single().state.data
    val criteria = QueryCriteria.VaultQueryCriteria(externalIds = listOf(myAccount.identifier.id))

    //Ticket
    val ticketList = serviceHub.vaultService.queryBy<NonFungibleToken>(criteria = criteria).states
    val myTicketIDs = ticketList.map { it.state.data.tokenType.tokenIdentifier }
    val tkList = myTicketIDs.map {
        val uuid = UUID.fromString(it)
        val queryCriteria = QueryCriteria.LinearStateQueryCriteria(uuid = listOf(uuid),status = Vault.StateStatus.UNCONSUMED)
        val stateAndRef = serviceHub.vaultService.queryBy<T20CricketTicketState>(queryCriteria).states[0]
        val description = stateAndRef.state.data.ticketTeam
        description
    }
    //Assets
    val asset = serviceHub.vaultService.queryBy(FungibleToken::class.java, criteria).states
    val myMoney = asset.map { it.state.data.amount.quantity.toString() + " " + it.state.data.tokenType.tokenIdentifier}
    return "\nI have ticket(s) for $tkList" +
            "\nI have money of $myMoney"
}}
```

Full code at: https://github.com/corda/samples-kotlin/tree/master/Accounts/worldcupticketbooking

Comment: Peter, please read the last sentence in my question :-) Anyway, I found the answer myself.